# How to get all content from a text box in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am facing some hard-times with my new project. Basically, what I need is to get all the text in this html code segment using Python Selenium Webdriver.

The part that I need:

```
<div class="both"></div>




<div class="st-box" id="source-code">
    <h3>CÓDIGO FONTE</h3>

    <div class="wrap code-answer-1">

        <pre id="code" class="code-2">
#include &lt;bits/stdc++.h&gt;

using namespace std;


int main(){
  double v, d;
  while(cin &gt;&gt; v &gt;&gt; d)
  {
    double a = (d/2.)*(d/2.) * 3.14;
    // v = a * h , h = v / a
    printf(&quot;ALTURA = %.2lf\nAREA = %.2lf\n&quot;, v/a, a);
  }

}
</pre>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need everything that is after `#include`.

My script is working weird. I can't get anything that is more than 33 lines of text. Also, 33 lines of text is the number of lines that appears in the page (I have to scroll down ***inside*** the text-box, to see more text). I can't find a way to do this and get the whole text, I've tried many things, and also some questions I could find here.

Full page html code: https://ghostbin.com/paste/homo8

My script: https://ghostbin.com/paste/5re7h

Comment: Oh it would be nice if I can get it **rendered** already, like as post-html text!

Comment: If you're not planning to simulate a real user (i.e., via browser), then you may as well use a simple socket (e.g., `urllib2.urlopen`) rather than something as "heavy" as `selenium.webdriver`.

Comment: This is very broad. The community responds better if you ask a specific question on where you got stuck and what happened. Imagine you're asking a busy coworker to help you: would you tell them that you "need everything past the #include line"? You should [learn how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).